# How can I pipe a prompt string (PS1) into a command and have the text result be PS1?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, ps1

What I currently have in my .bash_profile is

```
export PS1="\w ↪ Bob♔ Home > "
```

What I wish to do is something like

```
export PS1="\w ↪ Bob♔ Home > " | lolcat
```

where the normal string used for the prompt is piped into the lolcat command, and the result of that is used for PS1. How might I go about doing this task?

**Update 1:**

Any other way to make PS1 randomly rainbow colored would be an acceptable alternative as well.

**Final Update**

There was no answer to the original question, so I selected chw21's answer as it was the true 'answer' to the original question.

Since I couldn't use lolcat, I used the following code in my .bash_profile

```
randomNumberGen() { while :; do ran=$RANDOM; ((ran < 32760)) && echo $(((ran%7)+1)) && break; done }
numberRandom=$(randomNumberGen)
red=$(tput setaf 9)
orange=$(tput setaf 208)
yellow=$(tput setaf 11)
green=$(tput setaf 10)
blue=$(tput setaf 33)
indigo=$(tput setaf 12)
violet=$(tput setaf 55)
resetColor=$(tput sgr0)
if [ $numberRandom -eq 1 ]; then listVar=($red $orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 2 ]; then listVar=($orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet $red);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 3 ]; then listVar=($yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet $red $orange);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 4 ]; then listVar=($green $blue $indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 5 ]; then listVar=($blue $indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow $green);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 6 ]; then listVar=($indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow $green $blue);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 7 ]; then listVar=($violet $red $orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo);else echo "WHAT HAVE YOU DONE";fi
export PS1="\w \[${listVar[0]}\]↪ S\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[1]}\]am\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[2]}\]pl\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[3]}\]e♔\[$resetColor\] \[${listVar[4]}\]Ho\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[5]}\]me\[$resetColor\] \[${listVar[6]}\]> \[$resetColor\]"
export PROMPT_COMMAND='numberRandom=$(randomNumberGen);if [ $numberRandom -eq 1 ]; then listVar=($red $orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 2 ]; then listVar=($orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet $red);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 3 ]; then listVar=($yellow $green $blue $indigo $violet $red $orange);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 4 ]; then listVar=($green $blue $indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 5 ]; then listVar=($blue $indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow $green);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 6 ]; then listVar=($indigo $violet $red $orange $yellow $green $blue);elif [ $numberRandom -eq 7 ]; then listVar=($violet $red $orange $yellow $green $blue $indigo);else echo "WHAT HAVE YOU DONE";fi;export PS1='\''\w \[${listVar[0]}\]↪ S\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[1]}\]am\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[2]}\]pl\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[3]}\]e♔\[$resetColor\] \[${listVar[4]}\]Ho\[$resetColor\]\[${listVar[5]}\]me\[$resetColor\] \[${listVar[6]}\]> \[$resetColor\]'\'''
```

Explanation of code:

First, a random integer is chosen between one to seven (inclusive) when the randomNumberGen function is executed. The result of which is the value for numberRandom.

Then, the colors of the rainbow (ROYGBIV) individually are set to the corresponding color using tput.

For the seven cases possible, there is a list created with an ordering of ROYGBIV.

Once the list is created, the PS1 has colors added to it using the list items as colors.

*Note: Although this does work, I do not like how it looks. So, I will probably have seven lists, one for each color of the rainbow, and have the items for each of the seven lists be a light to dark spectrum of the color.*

Comment: https://github.com/Velaseriat/RainbowColoredBashPrompt You can manually set the color of the text. It was annoying to set up the array of colors. I am not good at bash but this works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought about making this a comment, because it doesn't answer the specific question, but it's too long.

Fundamentally you can include the output of a program in your `PS1`:

```
PS1="\$(ls -m) $ "
```

However, `lolcat` seems to have its own method of colouring up the letters, which is incompatible. When I tried

```
PS1="\$(echo \"\w ↪ Bob♔ Home > \" | lolcat)"
```

there was no colour. And when I tried to force lolcat, like this:

```
PS1="\$(echo \"\w ↪ Bob♔ Home > \" | lolcat -f)"
```

the result was a mess.

Comment: Is there another way of making my PS1 randomly rainbow colored then?